# Mysql: Find entries from specific day using timestamp column

Tags: mysql, timestamp

My each row have time-stamp column (called 'timestamp'). How can I find all rows from specific day?

I've tried calculating start/end of the day, but i'm looking for a better way.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to extract just the date part, using DATE() function:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE DATE(your_column) = '2013-07-03'
```

or you can use this, that can make use of an index:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE your_column >= '2013-07-03' AND
      your_column < '2013-07-03' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

use the date function:

```
select date('2013-07-03 15:58:37');
```

Comment: But this way I'll only get rows for speccyfic timestamp. am I right? I need All rows from 0:00 to 23:59

Comment: @PsychoX, the `date` function returns the date part from the given `datetime` expression.  Please go through the following documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: @PsychoX and isn't that you want? a better way than indicate the second where the day starts and ends?