# How to query a table based on timestamp with date in dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing a field "created_at" whose Data Type is timestamp. I donot want to change it to DATE.

Can i query this table to fetch all rows of a day in format dd-mm-yyyy.

Note: 
One approach I tried is:
a) Take Date in yyyy-mm-dd concatenate with 00:00:00
b) Take next date in yyyy-mm-dd concatenate with 00:00:00
and use below query to get all records of that day:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM news
 WHERE created>='2016-12-13 00:00:00'AND
created < '2016-12-14 00:00:00'
```

Is this a good solution to my problem. Any better approach for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL `cast()` function.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM news 
WHERE CAST(created_at AS DATE) = '2016-12-13'
```

This will discard the time component of your timestamp and do the comparison on only the date.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: for me also just ommitting the 00:00:00 worked, but i would say that casting is for sure safer option

Comment: Can i also use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449920/mysql-find-entries-from-specyfic-day-using-timestamp-collumn

Comment: Yes, the `DATE()` function is basically a wrapper around casting.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change column datatype then you can go with this code

```
$startDate = strtotime( '2016-12-13' ); // it will convert date to timestamp format.
$endDate = strtotime( '2016-12-15');
$query = "SELECT *  FROM news WHERE created >= '$startDate' AND created < '$endDate'";
```